# Git stash possible to apply stash created by another user?

Tags: git, git-stash

I want to share my stash with my friend and looking for ways to "upload" my stash to the git repo so that he/she can "download" the stash.

Is that possible and if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm has a feature call `shelve changes` [details](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html) i.e. similar to *SVN shelve*. So if you use this IDE, proceed steps below.

1. Shelve your changes
2. Commit-push PyCharm project data i.e. `.idea/shelf` folder

Other teammates will just git-pull your *shelve changes* and `unshelve` in PyCharm.

Answer (score 2):

Create a branch, apply the stash to that branch, then push the branch to a shared repository.

Comment: Oh, so we can't save the stash directly... Nice idea, thank you!

Comment: Though the apply/pop action seems to rely on branch actions - this is not what we want I guess